# Prevent multiple words form field PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a sign-up form that just sends us an email when submitted. Can I trim the suggested username field to prevent multiple words from being entered? Or perhaps automatically eliminate the spaces upon submit to form a single word?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [`preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) In your case, you would want:

```
// \s+ means 1 or more whitespace characters.
// '' means that the whitespace will be replaced by emptiness.
// so this should return a string which replaces all whitespace with nothing
preg_replace("#\s+#g", '', $string);
```